# Scrapy screenshot

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, scrapy, screenshot

I've been working recently with scrapy and I would like to take screenshot of a website. I found this: https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-selenium/ and thought to make use of it. I created this file:

```
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest

CHROME_PATH = '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS = "--headless"

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800
}

def main():
    yield SeleniumRequest(
        url='https://chainz.cryptoid.info/ltc/wallet.dws?1231.htm',
        callback=parse_result,
        screenshot=True
        )

def parse_result(response):
    with open('image.png', 'wb') as image_file:
        image_file.write(response.meta['screenshot'])

main()
```

But nothing appears in my directory after execution. Is it no longer supported/broken or am I missing something? Thanks for any hint.